# make negative margin-left increase as window is scaled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I make a margin-left:0vw of mydiv-2 go into a negative margin-left and increasingly more negative margin-left as the browser window is scaled further and further down horizontally.

```css
#mydiv-1{
  background-color:orange;
  width:60%;
  height:400px;
 margin-left: 150px
  }

#mydiv-2{
  background-color:blue;
  margin-left:0vw;
  width:30%;
  height:150px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="mydiv-1">
  <div id="mydiv-2">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: been thinking but don't know where to begin

Comment: You know what you want to do. All you need is to find the knowledge on how to accomplish your task. What you need to ask here is a [mcve]

Comment: I'll add some code though to get things set up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to do:

```
#mydiv-2{
  background-color:blue;
  margin-left: -2vw;
  width:30%;
  height:150px;
  }
```

When the window will decrease, that vw will decrease with it

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is when the window decreases in size width, then that the negative margin increases, not decreases.

Comment: Do you mean increase as in `-10 -> -20`? or `-20 -> -10`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I mean -10 -> -20

Comment: Ah. Then you mean decrease. :)